# How to process GuzzleHTTP async requests without blocking?

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle

I need to write a processor that can potentially send out many HTTP requests to an external service. Since I want to maximize performance, I wish to minimize blocking. I'm using PHP 5.6 and GuzzleHTTP.

GuzzleHTTP does have an option for async requests. But since we do have only 1 thread available in PHP, I need to allocate some time for them to be processed. Unfortunately I only see one way to do it - calling `wait` which blocks until all the requests are processed. That's not what I want.

Instead I'd like to have some method that handles whatever has arrived, and then returns. So that I can do something along the lines of:

```
$allRequests = [];

while ( !checkIfNeedToEnd() ) {
    $newItems = getItemsFromQueue();
    $allRequests = $allRequests + spawnRequests($newItems);
    GuzzleHttp::processWhatYouCan($allRequests);
    removeProcessedRequests($allRequests);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright... figured it out myself:

```
$handler = new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler();
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['handler' => $handler]);
$promise1 = $client->getAsync("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
$promise2 = $client->getAsync("http://localhost/");

$doneCount = 0;

$promise1->then(function() use(&$doneCount) {
    $doneCount++;
    echo 'Promise 1 done!';
});
$promise2->then(function() use(&$doneCount) {
    $doneCount++;
    echo 'Promise 2 done!';
});

$last = microtime(true);
while ( $doneCount < 2 ) {
    $now = microtime(true);
    $delta = round(($now-$last)*1000);
    echo "tick($delta) ";
    $last = $now;

    $handler->tick();
}
```

And the output I get is:

> tick(0) tick(6) tick(1) tick(0) tick(1001) tick(10) tick(96) Promise 2 done!tick(97) Promise 1 done!

The magic ingredient is creating the `CurlMultiHandler` yoursef and then calling `tick()` on that when it's convenient. After that it's promises as usual. And if the queue is empty, `tick()` returns immediately.

Note that it can still block for up to 1 second (default) if there is no activity. This can be also changed if needed:

```
$handler = new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler(['select_timeout' => 0.5]);
```

The value is in seconds, but with floating point.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you!